# does HTTP status code 403 affect traffic?

Tags: php, http, traffic

my site opens, but when I query HTTP status code 403 is the reason that the traffic has dropped too recently?

HTTP status

[image: HTTp status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of 403 Forbidden Errors

403 errors are almost always caused by issues where you're trying to access something that you don't have access to. The 403 error is essentially saying "Go away and don't come back here."

> https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989

Answer (score 0):

Yes, site traffic will be affected by this situation. Site response must be 200 OK.